# Android Register Form with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm going to create a simple register form app that when user insert their **username** and **password**, **EditText** in UI shows the **id** of their record in database.

My app insert users into database correctly; Just my **EditText** doesn't show **id** ...

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#00aeef"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="Register Example"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:text="Username:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_username"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:ems="10"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_insert"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edt_result"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edt_password"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:text="Insert"
    android:textColor="#00aeef" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edt_username"
    android:text="Password:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_password"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edt_username"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:ems="10"
    android:padding="5dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_result"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_insert"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:ems="10"
    android:padding="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**InsertClass.java**

```
package com.example.testphp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class InsertClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

private Context context;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private EditText edt;
private String json = "";   
private JSONObject jObj = null;

public InsertClass(Context context, EditText edt)
{
    this.context = context;
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    this.edt = edt;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading... Please wait");
    pDialog.show();
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

    try
    {
    String username = (String)arg0[0];
    String password = (String)arg0[1];
    String link = "http://10.0.2.2:8020/test/test.php";
    String data = URLEncoder.encode("username","utf-8") + 
    "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username,"utf-8");
    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password","utf-8") + 
            "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password,"utf-8");
    URL url = new URL(link);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(data);
    wr.flush();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        sb.append(line);
        break;
    }
    json = sb.toString();
    jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    edt.setText(jObj.getString("id"));
    return sb.toString();
    }
    catch(JSONExeption e)
    {
        return new String("Exeption: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return new String("Exeption: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    pDialog.dismiss();
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.testphp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String username;
String password;
EditText edtUsername;
EditText edtPassword;
EditText edtResult;
Button btnInsert;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnInsert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_insert);
    edtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_password);
    edtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_username);
    edtResult = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_result);

    btnInsert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            username = edtUsername.getText().toString();
            password = edtPassword.getText().toString();
            new InsertClass(MainActivity.this, edtResult).execute(username,password);

        }
    });

}

    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**test.PHP**

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost" , "root" , "","test");
if(mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
} 
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO test (username,pass) VALUES '$username','$password')");
if($result)
{
$id_result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM test WHERE username = $username");
if($id_result)
{
$response = array("id" => $id_result);
echo json_encode($response);
}
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Any suggestion, would be appreciated ...

Comment: Have you heard about **SQL injection**? This would be the first obvious suggestion.

Comment: you are catching an exception and do nothing with it (do at least `e.printStackTrace()` to see it in Logcat) ...  and i'm pretty sure that you are hurting UI with bad touch, UI doesn't like to be touched from not UI thread

Comment: @shadyyx, Also, I've never heard SQL Injection !!! Tanks for your hint.By the Way, at first, I'm going to crate my app structure and then I'll add security policy to it ...

Comment: @Selvin, As **Fred -ii-** mentioned, I lost quotation ('$username') in select statement ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Far as I can see, you have 2 errors in your SQL.

This line is missing a bracket:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO test (username,pass) VALUES  '$username','$password')");
                                                                     ^ bracket
```

Which should read as:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO test (username,pass) VALUES ('$username','$password')");
```

This line is missing quotes for `$username`

```
$id_result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM test WHERE username = $username");
```

Which should read as:

```
$id_result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM test WHERE username = '$username'");
```

Add `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()` to see the actual error.

You should also guard against SQL injection, change your POST variables to:

```
$username = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);

$password = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
```

Look into [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

I won't be able to help you with the Android code, but see what Selvin mentioned in a comment:

> *"you are catching an exception and do nothing with it (do at least `e.printStackTrace()` to see it in Logcat) ... and i'm pretty sure that you are hurting UI with bad touch, UI doesn't like to be touched from not UI thread"*

Comment: Tanks for your hint. I checked my select statement and I've lost quotation for **$username**. Also, I added or **die(mysqli_query($con)** to my statements. Now, my EditText fillout with this message:

Comment: {"lenghts:"null,"num_rows:"null,"type:"null,"current_field:"null,"field_count:"null} -------- Do you know what is meaning ?!

Comment: Not quite sure but if that is the actual code you got, the word `lenghts` is mispelled and should read as `lengths` @FarshadKazemi is that word `lenghts` part of your code somewhere?

Comment: @FarshadKazemi OK. Well there is a funky character between the `n` and `ull` in `field_count:"n‌​ull` so if that is part of your code, the error may lie in there. It's hard to say at this point, since I do not know anything about Android, so it's that much more difficult for me to properly diagnose the problem.

Comment: I searched for this error in **stackoverflow** and I found that I must add this line to my php cod(after if($result)):   **$id_result = mysqli_fetch_array($id_result)** --- Tanks a lot for your supports

Comment: @FarshadKazemi By adding that, did it fix your code?

Comment: Just I have a little problem with my JSON ... are you familiar with JSON ?! my result String is like that: **{"id":"21","0":"21"}** ---- **21** is id of my inserted username and it is correct. just I want catch **21** instead of above JSON object

Comment: @FarshadKazemi No, I'm not familiar with JSON, just MySQL and PHP.

Comment: PHP side of my Question was solved with adding **mysqli_fetch_array()** function. Tanks again for your hints ..